# Can we simulate a Hammer.js "press" using Selenium WebDriver with ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a WebApp, I am trying to simulate a [Hammer.js "press"](https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-press/) (a long-press vs a simple 'Click') using [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) with ChromeDriver. Coming up empty on searches.

Something like a `driver.FindElement(By.Id("elem_id")).ClickLong()`?

***Edit: Figures... just saw [THIS](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/#click-and-hold) - will investigate and get back..***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - here we go. Sorry for the VB.

First for the documentation: [**Selenium Actions for ClickAndHold**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/#click-and-hold).

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions

Dim opts = New ChromeOptions With {.BinaryLocation = "pathTo_Chrome.exe"}
Dim d As ChromeDriver = New ChromeDriver("pathTo_ChromeDriver", opts)

'... (you would probably have all the above already setup)

 Sub LongPress(d As ChromeDriver, elemId As String)
    Dim actions As Actions = New Actions(d)
    Dim wElem As IWebElement = d.FindElement(By.Id(elemId))
    actions.ClickAndHold(wElem).Perform()
    actions.Release()    'releases at virtual "click" at last mouse position
End Sub
```

###### Function will be used like:

`LongPress(d, "elemId")`

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but I'm off to the races again. Hope this helps.